# 2 CentOS boxes - one can't SSH to the other using publickey auth?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, ssh-keys

I have 2 CentOS boxes with literally identical sshd configs and overall setups.

Box A can SSH to Box B just fine, but Box B can't SSH to Box A using publickey authentication (works fine with password auth). I've checked and re-checked the keys, setup, etc. literally 100 times and it just won't work.

When Box B offers the RSA public key to Box A, Box A literally just seems to ignore it. Normally it should return a packet of "type 60" but instead it again returns a type 51 and re-announces the authentications that can continue.

Here's the debug info. Does anyone have any idea what might cause this?

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/patrick/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
...
```

And here's the relevant part of my /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
GatewayPorts no
AllowTcpForwarding yes
KeepAlive yes
Protocol 1,2
Port 8855
IgnoreRhosts yes
IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
PrintMotd yes
StrictModes yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
RSAAuthentication yes
```

And this is using OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips on both boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Crazy, it was an selinux issue. Just figured it out. I had to do:

restorecon -R -v /home/patrick/.ssh

Just putting this here for posterity ...